# printing Beautiful Soup value returns something different than value shown on website

Tags: html, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

Ive been learning python for a couple of months and been practicing with some web scraping. To get some references ive been using a book off amazon (O'Reilly) and it has an example that has me a bit confused.

The code is as follows:

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("https://isitchristmas.com"), "html.parser")
print (bsObj.find("a", {"id":"answer"}).attrs['title']) #returns "IFTTT"
```

However, I compared it to the code on the page and as you can see the value at title is not IFTTT, its "NO"

```
<a id="answer" href="https://ifttt.com/isitchristmas" target="_blank" title="NO">NO</a>
```

To sum things up, I dont get why it gives me different values if im looking at the same attribute of the same tag.

The only thing I could see is a comment that says:

```
<!--
    Initial 'title' and noscript values are server-side fallbacks,
    calculated with UTC, for clients who do not have JS enabled.
  -->
```

Still, I would appreciate if someone could help me understand this or point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (bsObj.find("a", {"id":"answer"}).text)
```

This is HTML code:

```
<a id="answer" href="https://ifttt.com/isitchristmas" target="_blank" title="IFTTT">
<noscript>NO</noscript>
```

What you need is `string` of a tag, not the `title` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, Im still getting the hang of some of the syntax and concepts.

Comment: @rammpeth in the` <attr1='', attr2=''>`, there are attrs, between '<>string<\>', that is string/text.